# Avoid applying style to :after when using :hover

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I am using :after to allow myself a border with a radius and a gradient, like:

```
 #main .element {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #FFF;
    }

 #main .element:after {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
      top: -7px;
      bottom: -7px;
      left: -7px;
      right: -7px;
      z-index:-1;
    }
```

I want the element in question to change its background colour when it is being hovered over, like:

```
#main .element:hover {
  background: #F00;
}
```

The problem is that the :after pseudo element gets selected too, and its background is also changed - I do not want the :after style to be effected when hovering over the element - I want the border to maintain its background colour.
Any suggestions on how to do this? I would prefer to use CSS but I am not against using jquery if need be. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the CSS you've posted is causing the problem? It seems fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gb8362x6/

Comment: Cannot replicate - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xydj02rc/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Probably because neither of you are reproducing the problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `:after` is inheriting the style from the parent, as [this jsfiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobgray/ej4k5Lqh/).
Your problem is that the `:after`'s css is missing a couple of key properties:

```
#main .element:after {
  /* :before and :after elements *must* have `content` set, even if it is empty*/
  content: "";
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  /* :after also doesn't have any size, since you never position it. Without a non-static position, top, bottom, etc. are ignored*/
  position:absolute;
  top: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```